# Building new pandas DataFrame using dict of row selections (cannot reindex from a duplicate axis)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas `DataFrame` and several lists of row indices. My goal is to use these row indices to create columns in a new dataset based on the corresponding values in a given the original `DataFrame`, and make boxplots from this. My lists of row indices are associated with names. I represent this as a dictionary of lists of row indices.

The following small example works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        "col2" : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]},
    index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
lists_of_indices = {
    "A" : ["a", "c", "d"],
    "B" : ["b", "c", "f"],
    "D" : ["a", "d"]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {list_name : df.loc[id_list]["col1"] for (list_name, id_list) in lists_of_indices.items()})
new_df.plot.box()
```

However, with my real data, I end up with a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

**What can be the problem, and how do I fix it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, some of the lists of indices may have duplicates. Simply transforming them in a `set` can solve the issue:

Here is an example that reproduces the error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        "col2" : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]},
    index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
lists_of_indices = {
    "A" : ["a", "c", "d"],
    "B" : ["b", "c", "f", "c"], # Note the extra "c"
    "D" : ["a", "d"]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {list_name : df.loc[id_list]["col1"] for (list_name, id_list) in lists_of_indices.items()})
new_df.plot.box()
```

And here is how to fix it:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {list_name : df.loc[set(id_list)]["col1"] for (list_name, id_list) in lists_of_indices.items()})
```

It might however be worthwhile to check why some of these lists of indices contain duplicates in the first place.